# Graphics window that creates a checkerboard with 64 squares,python

Tags: python

```
from graphics import GraphicsWindow

win=GraphicsWindow(400,400)
canvas=win.canvas()
canvas.setFill("black")
#first line 
canvas.drawRect(10,10,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(30,10,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(50,10,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(70,10,10,10)
#second line
canvas.drawRect(20,20,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(40,20,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(60,20,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(80,20,10,10)
#third line 
canvas.drawRect(10,30,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(30,30,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(50,30,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(70,30,10,10)
#fourth line
canvas.drawRect(20,40,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(40,40,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(60,40,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(80,40,10,10)
#fifth line
canvas.drawRect(10,50,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(30,50,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(50,50,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(70,50,10,10)
#sixth line
canvas.drawRect(20,60,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(40,60,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(60,60,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(80,60,10,10)
#seventh line
canvas.drawRect(10,70,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(30,70,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(50,70,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(70,70,10,10)
#eighth line
canvas.drawRect(20,80,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(40,80,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(60,80,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(80,80,10,10)
win.wait()
```

So This will create a checkerboard with 64 black squares, but I feel as though this is more code then necessary. How can I change it so that lines 1,3,5,7 and lines 2,4,6,8 are able to be printed by only increasing the y coordinate (x,y,height,width) and not having this insane amount of code?

Something like this?

```
canvas.drawRect(10,,10,10).formatrange(y,10,30,50,70)
canvas.drawRect(30,,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(50,,10,10)
canvas.drawRect(70,,10,10)
```

Keep in mind my code does work, I just want to make it look better with less clutter.

Comment: Try using loops maybe? Define a list of coordinates and iterate over it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Gabe what is the difference between the two sites?

Comment: @Jake: This site is for code that doesn't work; *codereview* is for code that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple loop:

```
for y in range(1, 9):
    for x in range(4):
        base = 20 if y % 2 == 0 else 10
        canvas.drawRect(base + (x * 20), y * 10, 10, 10)
```

Here `y` ranges from 1 to 8 inclusive, and multiplying that by 10 gives us 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. For every `y`, `x` ranges from 0 to 3 inclusive, and multiplying that by 20 gives 0, 20, 40, and 60. Adding 10 or 20 gives you your range of 10 - 70 or 20 - 80.

Using `itertools.product()` would let you eliminate one loop:

```
from itertools import product

for y, x in product(range(1, 9), range(4)):
    base = 20 if y % 2 == 0 else 10
    canvas.drawRect(base + (x * 20), y * 10, 10, 10)
```

Quick demo just printing the coordinates used:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for y, x in product(range(1, 9), range(4)):
...     base = 20 if y % 2 == 0 else 10
...     print (base + (x * 20), y * 10)
... 
(10, 10)
(30, 10)
(50, 10)
(70, 10)
(20, 20)
(40, 20)
(60, 20)
(80, 20)
(10, 30)
(30, 30)
(50, 30)
(70, 30)
(20, 40)
(40, 40)
(60, 40)
(80, 40)
(10, 50)
(30, 50)
(50, 50)
(70, 50)
(20, 60)
(40, 60)
(60, 60)
(80, 60)
(10, 70)
(30, 70)
(50, 70)
(70, 70)
(20, 80)
(40, 80)
(60, 80)
(80, 80)
```

Comment: base=20, That is really cool. I'm still trying to understand it, but that it much easier then what I did. Thank you

Comment: So this line     base = 20 if y % 2 == 0 else 10 will take the even values and time by 20, otherwise take the odd and multiply by 10?

Comment: @Jake: Not multiply; *add* to. But if `y` is even, `20` is used as the base, otherwise `10` is used, yes.

Comment: @Jake: `x` is a number between 0 and 3; so you get `0 * 20 + (10 or 20 depending on y)` is `0 + 10` or `0 + 20` for `x == 0`, `1 * 20 + 10` or `1 * 20 + 20` for `x == 1`, etc.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I understand it but trying to read the code and think of all the outputs is making me over think it. So, ill have to look at it again some other time or try coding something in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

> but I feel as though this is more code then necessary

You certainly have the right feel about it ;)

```
for j in range(10, 90, 10):
    for j in range(10, 90, 20):
    if j % 2 == 1:
        for i in 10, 30, 50, 70:
            canvas.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10)
    else:
        for i in 20, 40, 60, 80:
            canvas.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10)
```

Or if you move the `if` inside the second loop:

```
for j in range(10, 90, 10):
    for i in 10, 30, 50, 70:
        if j % 2 == 1:
            canvas.drawRect(i + 10, j, 10, 10)
        else:
            canvas.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10)
```

Or a bit different but even shorter:

```
for j in range(10, 90, 10):
    start = 10 if j % 2 == 1 else 20
    for i in range(start, 90, 20):
        canvas.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10)
```